# is restful webservice is possible with HTTPs?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, https

I have implemented restful webservice with Http (in localhost).Now  am using the same code for https.(only alerted the url) it is not working? what are the changes to be done can someone help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: What software are you using to host the service on your localhost?

Comment: Jersy core 1.6 and jettison 1.1 jar.I  am using the same jars for https too.should i have to use any other jars for https?

Answer (score 0):

It might be https configuration problem.

Make sure that your application server is correctly configured with SSL certificates and all other web pages can access through https.

Comment: Thanks for your response Shahul3D.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible, and it's highly encouraged to avoid Man In The Middle attacks.

Https is only encrypted http, you have probably a configuration problem.

The Twitter apis are on https: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json

Answer (score 0):

For use of HTTPS, you can check documentation in jersey.java.net on http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/client-api.html#d4e778

=> chapter : Security with Http(s)URLConnection